# C-library consists of asynchronous DNS resolver

Tags: c, dns, sip

Need to find a asynchronous DNS resolver implemented in C (except Sofia Resolver) which supports DNS queries for NAPTR, SRV and A records. It would be desired to support internal caching. Any suggestions/recommendations?
Currently looking at ldns which supports NAPTR, SVC and A queries. But, If I have understood correctly, it is not asynch DNS resolver.

Comment: Have you considered adding NAPTR support to libadns yourself?

Comment: If there is not another asynch DNS resolver which supports NAPTR queries, this is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

[c-ares](http://c-ares.haxx.se/), which is used within libCurl, is an asynchronous resolver.

Comment: c-ares does not support NAPTR queries:
ares_parse_a_reply(),
ares_parse_aaaa_reply(),
ares_parse_ns_reply(),
ares_parse_ptr_reply(),
ares_parse_srv_reply(),
ares_parse_txt_reply()

Comment: Ah, sorry.  It's open source, so you could add it. :)

Comment: @Joe Please reconsider this answer as (9 years later) c-ares seems to support NAPTR queries: https://c-ares.haxx.se/ares_parse_naptr_reply.html

Answer (score 1):

have you tried libunboud? Not sure about NAPTR

http://www.unbound.net/index.html